# The result of same script is displayed in two formats while calling using powershell.invoke and pipeline.invoke

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke-command

I am calling following script to display the local user accounts in a machine :

```
$adsi = [ADSI]'WinNT://localhost';
$adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} |Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}};
```

When the above script is executed using powershell.invoke, the result is

```
@{UserName=account17}
```

When the same script is executed using pipeline.invoke, the result is :

```
UserName
--------
account17
```

Why is there a difference in the output for the same script when invoked using powershell and pipeline?

Comment: What do you mean with powershell.invoke and pipeline.invoke? Invoke-Command {...} gives the same result as executing the script without it

Comment: Do you mean calling from C#? Can you show us more code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but the `powershell.invoke` output looks like an object-output via `write-host` and the `pipeline.invoke` looks like `write-output` output even though both should return a psobject.
More code would be helpful